# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fabSize'.compile sdk version is 24

Tags: android, git, firebase, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I have started "FireBase Essential Udacity course" download the code from git. I am using android studio compile sdk version on build gridle is also uptodate version 24 but still these errors coming.

> Error:(1530, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'fabSize'. Error:(1531, 21) No resource found that matches the given
>   name: attr 'rippleColor'. Error:(1530, 21) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'fabSize'. Error:(1531, 21) No resource
>   found that matches the given name: attr 'rippleColor'.

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.zar.shoppingfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Android Sdk**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Add compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0' (or the current version)

Comment: thanks i added it and now its working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line in your gradle file and build

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

It looks like you are using Floating Action Button but haven't add design library.